# Why 8086/8088 has OF in a high Flags byte?

Tags: cpu, intel, 8086, cpu-flag-bits

In 8086, OF is put not into low Flags byte as other flags but separated in the second (high) byte. This is followed then in all the x86 line.
Beside the possible historical reasons, this looks highly strange. The low byte still has only 5 used bits; 3 bits are hardwired (to 0 or 1).

Is there a known motivation for such a solution?

I seem failing to explain this with 8080 compatibility, as the latter has no OF at all, and a software wouldnʼt depend on spare bits.

Answer (score 4):

> I seem failing to explain this with 8080 compatibility,

But that's exactly the point here - that way the flag byte is fully 8080 compatible. No matter what any software does to these bits.  It will make sure that all (automatic) ported 8080 software does not create side effects.

There is no reason not to use the upper 8 bits, since the 8086 flag word is straight 16 bit (read: not twice 8). Using any of the upper 8 can be done freely, as they are unknown to and unreachable by 8080 software.

> as the latter has no OF at all, and a software wouldnʼt depend on spare bits.

But 'manually' creation of the flag byte could result in unintended (re-)setting them. Just imagine some software creating an 8080 flag byte, maybe to set various bits to return the result of a subroutine. no matter what default it uses, it would (re-)set OF as well.

Yes, this wouldn't matter in strict 8080 code, but what about the same software get enhanced at some point with 8086 code calling it? It opens all the problems of very nasty incompatibility issues. Keep in mind, this is all about continued use of large chunks of older software.

By keeping the lower 8 bit 100% 8080 compatible all of this is avoided at no cost.

---

This question opens a rather interesting follow up:

Why you assume it should have been moved into the lower 8 bit?

And what good would it have brought?

Comment: The only benefit I can see is it would make `LAHF/SAHF` more useful to native 8086 code, as they could then access the overflow flag.  There's no directly comparable instruction to transfer the whole 16-bit `FLAGS` to and from a general-purpose register; only `PUSHF/POPF` which are more awkward.

Comment: @NateEldredge Why? It's the only way to access the flag register on an 8080, so not really worse on the 8086. In fact, for 8086 code it would be really useful to be able to test or read the direction flag, as any routine using string operations need to manipulate it. Personally, in may years of 8086 programming, I never used LAHF at all. but ofc. that's just me.

Comment: @Raffzahn
"It will make sure that all (automatic) ported 8080 software does not create side effects." -

Unlikely: ported 8080 software would not use OF at all, so, spoiling of this flag would not affect it.

"There is no reason not to use the upper 8 bits" -

LAHF/SAHF were already named. More so, 8087 checks would use direct OF check instead of PF as do they now.

"Why you assume it should have been moved into the lower 8 bit?" -

E.g. 8087 use patterns (FSTSW+LAHF).

Comment: "but what about the same software get enhanced at some point with 8086 code calling it?" - Flags are never (except DF) requested to keep across subroutine calls. I canʼt imagine other variant of deep mixing of 80-ported and 86-native code.

Comment: @Netch _"Flags are never (except DF) requested to keep across subroutine calls"_ Who says that? Serious, in 'ye goode olde days' it was quite common to handle flags the same way as any other storage. Including certain routines not changing them. And yes, ported 8080 software would not use OV, but they do expect certain flag configuration - including the unused bits.

Comment: @Raffzahn "Including certain routines not changing them." - Then, they save full flags register and restore them. "but they do expect certain flag configuration - including the unused bits." - Really for unused ones? This may be _the_ reason but I hardly imagine such a case...

Comment: @Netch Keep in mind, the 8086 was a stop gap measure for embedded 8080 users, with software written at a time when every byte counted. Counted without any prefix. Even if spending the additional instructions and cycles for saving the flags was there, memory might have not. Not only were flags not saved, but as well artificial created as return information. Often by creating a flag word. Within 8080 code setting the unused bits to any value would be harmless, adding an OV flag there would make it prone to random setting.